# How to Port Forward with DSL Router + Wifi Router Configuration?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I got an ADSL router without Wi-Fi from my ISP. I bought a Netgear Wireless Router and connected them as follows:

Internet `>` ADSL Router `>` Wi-Fi Router `>` Computer

My ADSL router is a Huawei SmartAX MT880 and my Wi-Fi router is a NetGear Wireless-G WGR614

My torrent port is not open. So, I need to do port forwarding. I haven't done this before(ever!). So, in portforward.com, which guide should I follow (Huawei Guide or the NetGear one) ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to go out there and buy a combined device. First thing first - make sure the Netgear is actually in Bridged mode (best if you can get the Netgear in Bridged mode, even if it's not it's okay, just disable all firewall services on it then.)

After that, you follow Huawei's guide to port-forward the desired ports to your desired terminal.

Make sure you do a port-forward test though to ensure everything is working (go to the terminal where the port is forwarded to, and go [here](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)).

Answer (score 0):

I think probably both if the pc is connected to the wifi router.  You'll need to forward a port on the dsl router to a port on the wifi router, then that port would have to be forwarded to whichever PC it needs to go to.  Or you could just buy a combined device and save yourself a world of pain diagnosing things when they inevitably go wrong.